# Why am I getting segmentation fault 11?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This C program seems perfectly fine to me but it will not compile. The program is supposed to take a file with a list of words and phrases, and then print a new file with all the phrases that are matching anagrams. Could anyone help me find the reason? Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int are_anagram(char *word1, char *word2){
   int i,j;
   int found = 0;
   if (strlen(word1) != strlen(word2)){
      return 0;
   }
   for (i = 0; i<strlen(word1); i++){
       found = 0;
       for (j = 0; j<strlen(word2); j++){
          if (word1[i] == word2[j]){
             found = 1;
          }
       }
       if (found == 0){
          return found;
       }
   }
   for (i = 0; i<strlen(word2); i++){
       found = 0;
       for (j = 0; j<strlen(word1); j++){
          if (word2[i] == word1[j]){
             found = 1;
          }
       }
       if (found == 0){
          return found;
       }
   }
   return found;
}

int main(){

   char data[1000][50];
   int index[1000];

   FILE *fp,*fp1;
   int count;
   int i,j;

   fp = fopen("words.txt","r");
   fp1 = fopen("words.txt.ang","w");

   count = 0;
   while (fscanf(fp,"%s", data[count]) != EOF){
      index[count] = 0;
      count++;
   }
   for (i = 0; i<count; i++){
       for (j=0; j<count; j++){
          if (j!=i){
            // if (are_anagram(data[i],data[j]) && index[i] == 0 && 
    index[j] == 0){
                fprintf(fp1,"%s %s\n",data[i],data[j]);
                index[i] = 1;
                index[j] = 1;
             }
          }
       }
       fclose(fp);
       fclose(fp1);
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  You've provided code, which is an important part of creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  However, another part is having compilable code — what you show won't compile because of the comment.  And another part is providing example (minimal) data files.  You should describe your algorithm.

Comment: Normally, a good way of detecting anagrams is to sort (a copy of) the words such that the letters are in alphabetic order.  If the two sorted strings are the same, the corresponding words are anagrams.

Comment: But do you know why this is resulting in a segmentation fault?

Comment: No; the code you show in the question doesn't compile so you don't get a seg fault from it.

Comment: ・The file could not be opened. ・The number of words exceeds 1000. ・A word whose word length exceeds 49 exists. etc.

Comment: BTW It seems to be insufficient as a check of the anagram.